# flash player and asp.net button side by side

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to get a flash player by caster.fm and an asp.net button to side side by side

Currently they as expected just sit on top of each other, I have tried to wrap them in separate divs with a container div with no success.
I suspect the javacode in the flash player just wont let this be possible

```
<script type="text/javascript">var cstrpuid = 426247;var cstrpwidth = "400";var cstrpheight = "300";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="removed"></script>
<!--   DO NOT REMOVE THE LINKS BELOW, THEY  WILL BE HIDDEN (AND WILL HELP US A LOT)   -->
<a id="cstrplb" href="http://www.caster.fm/">Free Shoutcast Hosting</a><a id="cstrplb2" href="http://www.caster.fm/">Radio Stream Hosting</a>
<div id="cstrpdiv"></div>

<asp:Button ID="btnRadioStatus" runat="server" Text="Online Radio Status" Font-Size="XX-Large" Width="400" Height="30px" />
```

Comment: You removed the src of the JavaScript to generate the player. How are we supposed to reproduce the error and try to fix it?

Comment: added!.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Edge the button is below the player (which opens an annoying full screen popup). Haven't installed Flash in Firefox or Chrome.
 But it you give `cstrpdiv` the player width and height it should work in other browsers as well.

```
<div id="cstrpdiv" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; float: left;"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, i though it should be underneath. Change `clear:both` to `float: left`. And you can use CSS to further design the placing of the elements.